# Click on a particular row of MySql Table, such that it automatically creates a new file having data of that row in a PHP Web Page

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I just want to click on a row, such that it automatically creates a new file having the data of that particular row and also this file should be automatically downloaded. Please help me do this.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Click on Particular Row fo MySql Table, then Create New File having data of that Row in PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
 <table  class="table table-striped table-hover" border="1" id="dataTable1" style="text-align: justify;margin-left:30px;">
          <tr class="success" style="border-bottom: solid;border-top: solid;">
                            <th>
                                I.D.
                            </th>
                            <th>
                             Date
                            </th>
                            <th>
                            Website
                              </th>
                            <th>
                                 E-Mail
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Mobile&nbsp;Number(Head)
                            </th>                           
                            <th>
                            Courses
                            </th>
                                 <th>
                                File
                            </th>
                </tr>
                           <?php
                           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch))
                             {
                            ?>
                           <tr>
                               <td>
                                   <a href="Perticular.php?<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $row['id'];?></a> <!-- Want to Click on I.D. Such that Automatically Create New File having data of this whole Row -->
                               </td>
                               <td>
                                   <?php echo $row['date_Time'];?>
                               </td>                               
                               <td>
                                   <a href="<?php echo "http://".$row['website']; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $row['web_link'];?></a>  
                               </td>

                               <td>
                                  <?php echo $row['e_mail']; ?>
                               </td>

                               <td>
                                   <?php echo $row['mobile_number']; ?>
                               </td>
                               <td>
                                   <?php echo $row['courses_offer']; ?>
                               </td>

                               <td>
                                   <a href="uploaded/<?php echo $row['file_Attach'];?>" target="_blank">View File</a>
                               </td>
                           </tr>
                           <?php
                             }
                           ?>
                    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the info needed in a `hidden input` OR make a page which takes the `$_GET` value for row id, runs a query and outputs the info.

`Onclick`, bring up `hidden pop-up div` with an `iframe`. The page either takes the id/value from `$_GET`, runs query if needed, `file_put_contents($file, $data)` to output the data to a text file. Have a download link/image to download the file, pointing to just created file.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but i ask question first time on stackoverflow, So i didn't put the right code, but please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36886327/click-on-particular-row-of-mysql-table-such-that-automatically-create-new-file . And also i am biggner on JQuery and JavaScript. Can it done only through PHP, If Yes  then Please Answer on this Link , Otherwise Thanks, but please wright Full Code.